# Integrating BIRT with Esproc

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

We've been using Esproc with our BIRT reports for a while now and everything worked perfectly. We followed [this](https://datathinker.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/how-to-integrate-esproc-with-birt/) tutorial and things worked. However, the latest version of their software incorporated a couple of new functionalities and as such, we now need to upgrade the version running with BIRT. The thing is that now, nothing's working. We keep getting NullPointerException when trying to run reports. This is what we're getting so far:

```
The following report will be sent to Eclipse:

------
STATUS
------
pluginId            org.eclipse.jface
pluginVersion       3.12.0.v20160518-1929
code                2
severity            4
message             Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
fingerprint         eb22eddc61b2abbaef12193bb7441fab

Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     at com.esproc.jdbc.Server.getDfxList(Unknown Source:88)
     at com.esproc.jdbc.InternalConnection.getMetaData(Unknown Source:314)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.provider.JdbcMetaDataProvider.isSupportSchema(JdbcMetaDataProvider.java:305)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.editors.SQLDataSetEditorPage.createDBMetaDataSelectionComposite(SQLDataSetEditorPage.java:405)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.editors.SQLDataSetEditorPage.createPageControl(SQLDataSetEditorPage.java:334)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.editors.SQLDataSetEditorPage.createPageCustomControl(SQLDataSetEditorPage.java:307)
     at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui.wizards.DataSetWizardPage.createControl(DataSetWizardPage.java:123)
     at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.internal.ui.DataSetEditorPageCore.createContents(DataSetEditorPageCore.java:74)
     at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:241)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.PropertyPageWrapper.createPageControl(PropertyPageWrapper.java:61)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.PropertyNode.createPageControl(PropertyNode.java:238)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.showPage(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:577)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.showSelectionPage(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:482)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetEditor.showSelectionPage(DataSetEditor.java:913)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog$2$1.run(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:438)
     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog$2.selectionChanged(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:433)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:158)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
     at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:155)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2191)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1728)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1077)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:383)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.initTreeSelection(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:408)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.createDialogArea(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:299)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetEditor.createDialogArea(DataSetEditor.java:124)
     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetEditor.createContents(DataSetEditor.java:602)
     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.open(BaseDialog.java:107)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.EditDataSetAction.doAction(EditDataSetAction.java:105)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.AbstractElementAction.run(AbstractElementAction.java:70)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null:-1)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

------
REPORT
------
anonymousId         12355fbc-cb0f-41c4-b330-1d4a60fd5df2
name                
email               
comment             
eclipseBuildId      4.6.0.I20160606-1100
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_71-b15
osgiWs              win32
osgiOs              Windows10
osgiOsVersion       10.0.0
osgiArch            x86_64
severity            UNKNOWN

-------
BUNDLES
-------
name                org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui
version             4.6.0.v201606072122

name                org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc
version             4.6.0.v201606072122

name                org.eclipse.birt
version             4.6.0.v201606072122

name                org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui
version             4.6.0.v201606072122

name                org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.views
version             4.6.0.v201606072122

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.6.0.v20160511-1747

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.6.0.v20160412-0910

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.12.0.v20160606-1342

name                org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui
version             3.3.0.201603142002

name                org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design
version             3.4.0.201603142002

name                org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda
version             3.5.0.201603142002

name                org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity
version             1.13.0.201603142002

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.4.0.v20160517-1624

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.14.0.v20160523-1900

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.400.v20150715-1528

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.3.200.v20160318-1642

name                org.eclipse.jface
version             3.12.0.v20160518-1929

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.105.0.v20160603-0902

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.108.0.v20160518-1929

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.1.100.v20160518-1929

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.12.0.v20160601-1609
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to actually get things working and the solution isn't exactly what I'd call trivial. I actually had to modify and recompile three BIRT classes. You can easily get the source code [here](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php) if you don't want to do the Google search. Anyway, our first modification is given to us by the error message cited above. We need to alter `JdbcMetaDataProvider.java` located in the `org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar` package. What we're looking for is the `isSupportSchema()` method. and more specifically this bit of code:

```
try
{
    return connection.getMetaData( ).supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions( );
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    try 
    {
        reconnect( );
        return connection.getMetaData( ).supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions( );
    }
    catch ( Exception e1 )
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData( ).getSchemas( );
            if( rs != null )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (SQLException e2)
        {
            logger.log( Level.WARNING, e.getMessage( ), e1 );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Not having access to Esproc's code, I can't exactly say why it does this, but `connection.getMetaData( ).supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions( );` throws a NullPointerException. With no "catch" block to treat said exception, Eclipse will just stop its execution and prevent you from accessing your dataset. So we need to fix that like so:

```
try
{
    return connection.getMetaData( ).supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions( );
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    try 
    {
        reconnect( );
        return connection.getMetaData( ).supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions( );
    }
    catch ( Exception e1 )
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData( ).getSchemas( );
            if( rs != null )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (SQLException e2)
        {
            logger.log( Level.WARNING, e.getMessage( ), e1 );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
    return false;
}
```

Now then, the next two bits of code we need to alter are located in the `oda-jdbc.jar` package. The first one we're looking for is the `Connection.java` class and more specifically the method `populateConnectionProp( )`.

```
private void populateConnectionProp( ) throws SQLException
{
    if( jdbcConn!= null )
    {
        if( this.autoCommit != null )
            jdbcConn.setAutoCommit( this.autoCommit );
        else
        {
            if  (DBConfig.getInstance().qualifyPolicy(
                        jdbcConn.getMetaData().getDriverName(),
                        DBConfig.SET_COMMIT_TO_FALSE) ) {
                this.autoCommit = false;
                jdbcConn.setAutoCommit( false );
            }
        }
        if( this.isolationMode!= Constants.TRANSCATION_ISOLATION_DEFAULT)
            jdbcConn.setTransactionIsolation( this.isolationMode );
    }
}
```

This time the culprit throwing a `NullPointerException` is this line `jdbcConn.getMetaData().getDriverName()`. Again, not having access to Esproc's code, I don't really know why trying to recover the driver's name doesn't work, but anyway all we need to do is actually catch the exception and things will work normally again:

```
private void populateConnectionProp( ) throws SQLException
{
    if( jdbcConn!= null )
    {
        if( this.autoCommit != null )
            jdbcConn.setAutoCommit( this.autoCommit );
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if  (DBConfig.getInstance().qualifyPolicy(
                            jdbcConn.getMetaData().getDriverName(),
                            DBConfig.SET_COMMIT_TO_FALSE) ) {
                    this.autoCommit = false;
                    jdbcConn.setAutoCommit( false );
                }
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                this.autoCommit = false;
                jdbcConn.setAutoCommit( false );
            }
        }
        if( this.isolationMode!= Constants.TRANSCATION_ISOLATION_DEFAULT)
            jdbcConn.setTransactionIsolation( this.isolationMode );
    }
}
```

The other class we're looking for is the `CallStatement.java` class. In it we're going to have to locate the `getCallableParamMetaData()` method that I've pasted below:

```
private java.util.List getCallableParamMetaData( )
{
    java.util.List paramMetaDataList = new ArrayList( );
    try
    {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData( );
        String cataLog = conn.getCatalog( );
        String procedureNamePattern = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getProcedure( ) );
        String schemaPattern = null;
        if ( this.paramUtil.getSchema( ) != null )
        {
            schemaPattern = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getSchema( ) );
        }

        // handles schema.package.storedprocedure for databases such as
        // Oracle
        if ( !metaData.supportsCatalogsInProcedureCalls( ) )
        {
            if (this.paramUtil.getPackage( ) != null)
            {
                cataLog = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getPackage( ) );
            }
        }

        java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = metaData.getProcedureColumns( cataLog,
                schemaPattern,
                procedureNamePattern,
                null );
        while ( rs.next( ) )
        {
            ParameterDefn p = new ParameterDefn( );
            p.setParamName( rs.getString( "COLUMN_NAME" ) );
            p.setParamInOutType( rs.getInt( "COLUMN_TYPE" ) );
            p.setParamType( rs.getInt( "DATA_TYPE" ) );
            p.setParamTypeName( rs.getString( "TYPE_NAME" ) );
            p.setPrecision( rs.getInt( "PRECISION" ) );
            p.setScale( rs.getInt( "SCALE" ) );
            p.setIsNullable( rs.getInt( "NULLABLE" ) );
            if ( p.getParamType( ) == Types.OTHER )
                correctParamType( p );
            paramMetaDataList.add( p );
        }
        rs.close( );
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get SP paramters", e );
    }
    catch( JDBCException ex)
    {
        logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get SP paramters", ex );
    }

    return paramMetaDataList;
}
```

Basically, somewhere within the `while ( rs.next( ) )` loop lies the culprit throwing the NullPointerException. So all we need to do to is add a catch statement to treat it as follow:

```
private java.util.List getCallableParamMetaData( )
{
    java.util.List paramMetaDataList = new ArrayList( );
    try
    {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData( );
        String cataLog = conn.getCatalog( );
        String procedureNamePattern = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getProcedure( ) );
        String schemaPattern = null;
        if ( this.paramUtil.getSchema( ) != null )
        {
            schemaPattern = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getSchema( ) );
        }

        // handles schema.package.storedprocedure for databases such as
        // Oracle
        if ( !metaData.supportsCatalogsInProcedureCalls( ) )
        {
            if (this.paramUtil.getPackage( ) != null)
            {
                cataLog = getNamePattern( this.paramUtil.getPackage( ) );
            }
        }

        java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = metaData.getProcedureColumns( cataLog,
                schemaPattern,
                procedureNamePattern,
                null );
        while ( rs.next( ) )
        {
            ParameterDefn p = new ParameterDefn( );
            p.setParamName( rs.getString( "COLUMN_NAME" ) );
            p.setParamInOutType( rs.getInt( "COLUMN_TYPE" ) );
            p.setParamType( rs.getInt( "DATA_TYPE" ) );
            p.setParamTypeName( rs.getString( "TYPE_NAME" ) );
            p.setPrecision( rs.getInt( "PRECISION" ) );
            p.setScale( rs.getInt( "SCALE" ) );
            p.setIsNullable( rs.getInt( "NULLABLE" ) );
            if ( p.getParamType( ) == Types.OTHER )
                correctParamType( p );
            paramMetaDataList.add( p );
        }
        rs.close( );
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get SP paramters", e );
    }
    catch( JDBCException ex)
    {
        logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get SP paramters", ex );
    }
    catch( NullPointerException ex1)
    {
        logger.log( Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get SP paramters", ex1 );
    }
    return paramMetaDataList;
}
```

Once you've done your modifications to the files, you actually need to recompile your source code. To do this successfully, you're going to need to copy a couple of jars from Eclipse's plugin folder into the same folder as where you've placed the file you're trying to compile. The jars are given below in the command you need to enter to compile your source code. Here's what you need to enter in order to compile each file:

JdbcMetaDataProvider.java

```
javac -cp ".;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.bidi.utils_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar;
c:/mypath/oda-jdbc.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.5.0.201603142002.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design_3.4.0.201603142002.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui_3.3.0.201603142002.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.12.0.v20160420-0247.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.12.0.v20160420-0247.jar" JdbcMetaDataProvider.java > log.txt 2>&1
```

Connection.java

```
javac -cp ".;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.bidi.utils_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar;
c:/mypath/oda-jdbc.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.5.0.201603142002.jar;
c:/mypath/com.ibm.icu_56.1.0.v201601250100.jar" Connection.java > log.txt 2>&1
```

CallStatement.java

```
javac -cp ".;
c:/mypath/oda-jdbc.jar;
c:/mypath/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.5.0.201603142002.jar;
c:/mypath/com.ibm.icu_56.1.0.v201601250100.jar" CallStatement.java > log.txt 2>&1
```

Now, there's a couple of things that need to be said about the two above commands:

1) They actually need to be entered on one line. I merely broke them down like so for clarity purposes so that each jar needed was easy to spot.

2) This is actually a windows command. If you're running the command on Linux, each jar needs to be separated by a colon(:) instead of a semi-colon(;).

Once the compilation is successful, you'll end up with the following .class files:

```
JdbcMetaDataProvider$1TempThread.class
JdbcMetaDataProvider$2TempThread.class
JdbcMetaDataProvider.class

Connection$Constants.class
Connection.class

CallStatement.class
```

These need to be copied back into the original jar files so that they replace the files already there. Luckily, a jar file is nothing more than a zip file so in windows, any unzipping software will easily open things up for you and allow you to navigate to the proper folder.

Here are the the folders in question for each jar:

```
org\eclipse\birt\report\data\oda\jdbc\ui\provider\
org\eclipse\birt\report\data\oda\jdbc\
org\eclipse\birt\report\data\oda\jdbc\
```

Once that's done, restart Eclipse and things should work like normal again. I hope this helps someone in the future.